# How to convert an XML tree object to bytes stream? Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a function that saves files to a db, but this one requires a bytes stream as parameter. Something like:

```
write_to_db("File name", stream_obj)
```

Now, I want to save a XML; I am using the xml library.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
```

Is there a function that convert the xml object to bytes stream?
The solution I got was:

- Save it locally with the function write
- Retrieve it with "rb" to get the file as bytes
- Now that I have the bytes stream, save it with the function mentioned
- Delete the file

Example:

```
# Saving xml as local file
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.Element("Example")
tree.write("/This/is/a/path.xml")

# Reading local file as bytes
f = open("/This/is/a/path.xml", "rb")

# Saving to DB
write_to_db("File name", f) # <--- See how I am using "f" cuz I opened it as bytes with rb

# Deleting local file
os.remove("/This/is/a/path.xml")]
```

But is there a function from the xml library that returns automatically the bytes stream? Something like:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.Element("Example")
bytes_file = tree.get_bytes() # <-- Like this?

# Writing to db
write_to_db("File name", bytes_file)
```

This so I can prevent creating and removing the file in my repository.

Thank you in advance.

**Another fast question:**

Are the words "bytes stream" correct? or what is the difference? what would be the correct words that I am looking for?

Comment: `ET.tostring()` by default generates a bytes string. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=tostring#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring

Comment: Hi @balmy, Thank you so much. I read the documentation but missed that. I guess it was because I thought I would just receive a normal string of all the xml. hehe... Thanks!

Comment: If someone reading this has the following issue: AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'.
 
Don't use ET.ElementTree. I always use this to finish my xml. But it worked by just doing: ET.tostring(element_with_tag).

Comment: It’s a guess, but I think the confusing name `tostring()` which produces bytes is a legacy from ET’s origins in Python 2 when there wasn’t a distinction between bytes and str.

Answer (score 0):

So as Balmy mentioned in the comments, the solution is using:

```
ET.tostring()
```

My code at the end looked something like this:

```
# Here you build your xml
x = ET.Element("ExampleXML",{"a tag": "1", "another tag": "2"})

# Here I am saving it to my db by using the "tostring" function, 
# Which as default return the xml as a bytes stream string.
write_to_db("File name", ET.tostring(x))
```